# Getting oauth2-bearer working with simple-auth

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm a big fan of the quality of the code and documentation for Ember's simple-auth but coming back to it after a few months on a new project I'm running into what is probably just a stupid oversight but it is a blocker and I can't seem to figure it out.

I am following the basic installation directions and would like to use the out-of-the-box OAuth2 authenticator (resource owner flow). However, when I state the following configuration:

```js
// config/environment.js
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer',
  store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage'
};
```

I get the following error:

> The configured authorizer "simple-auth-authorizer:oauth2-bearer" could not be found in the container

I'm using Ember-CLI 0.1.15 and installed simple-auth through the appropriate *addon*. Also note, that while I installed using the `ember install:addon ember-cli-simple-auth` syntax and I also took the extra precaution of manually running `ember g ember-cli-simple-auth` just to make sure simple-auth had done all of it's needed initialisation.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Did you resolve it, if yes how please ?

Comment: This has been on he back burner for the past few weeks but I'll give this attention very soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Restarting the `ember serve` process solved it for me.

Comment: I've spent hours trying absolutely anything and everything to fix this. Never did it once occur to me that I had simply forgotten to restart the server. You quite possibly just saved me from jumping off a bridge/cliff, thank you for that.